List of lists (double [[) in Python
This is a really basic thing but after reading the documentation I am still not able to do. I just want to create a list of 9 sublists as follows
[[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25],[0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 25]]

I am doing
[np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05),
                 np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05),
                 np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05), np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05)]

but I get 24.9 , 24.95, 25.  ])], while I would like to get 24.9 , 24.95, 25.  ]])]. How can I get this done?

If you want lists, why are you using numpy.arange, a function that does not make lists?

What would you use? Thanks!

Depends on why you're using NumPy in the first place, and whether you really need lists. It sounds like you're not clear on the difference between lists and arrays, and what all those symbols you're seeing mean.

If you're just using NumPy because it looked like a convenient way to generate these lists, then I would probably write a list comprehension instead. If you really need to make use of NumPy functionality, then I would instead use numpy.linspace to generate a row (avoiding rounding issues that come up when using numpy.arange for that), then use something like numpy.tile to repeat that row into a 2D array.

Here's one list: [i * 0.05 for i in range(25*20 + 1)]

[[i*5/100 for i in range(501)] for _ in range(9)]

You can create such a list of lists wihtout numpy and converting ranges to and from lists.
Just use list concatenations to add elements to the lists:
The example below creates a smaller example:
[[x/20 for x in range(int(1.05*20))] for _ in range(3)]

The output is
[[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0], [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0], [0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]]

So, to generate the one you asked for in the original post would be:
[[x/20 for x in range(int(25.05*20))] for _ in range(9)]


It's best to use list():
step = 0.05
sublist = [round(i * step, 2) for i in range(int(25 / step) + 1)]
res = [sublist.copy() for _ in range(9)]
print(res)

You can use tolist() with deepcopy():
import numpy as np
import copy

sublist = np.arange(0, 25.05, 0.05).tolist()
res = [copy.deepcopy(sublist) for _ in range(9)]

print(res)

Note

This is an unnecessary way to do it, though. Just use list().

